# How to write Windows applications in PHP?

Tags: php, windows

I know PHP very good. I use it at work and overall we make nice websites. My question is - does anyone know how to make Windows applications in PHP? With Windows look and feel (not webapp but real Windows program). Is it possible?

Comment: Would you mind accepting an answer?

Answer (score 8):

For developing Windows applications I think it's better to learn C#, C or C++.

But yes, you can.

Here some ways for this:

Command Line PHP — is for developing shell applications with PHP;

PHP Desktop — is open source project for developing native desktop GUI applications using web technologies (PHP, HTML5, JavaScript & SQLite);

WinBinder — is a open source extension that allows PHP programmers to easily build native Windows applications;

Phalanger — is implementation of PHP, rewritten in C#. You can get access to C# libs;

ExeOutput — this makes it possible to create applications in native format for Windows with PHP, JavaScript and HTML;

PHP GTK — is an extension for the PHP programming language that implements language bindings for GTK+. But it is not supported from 2010;

Of course, maybe there are other ways, but I recommend you for creating Windows apps use something like C++, Python, Java, C#, etc. It's save your time and nerve.

Answer (score 2):

You'd better learn a new language.
The programmer selects the language to solve the problem, but not customize his skills under the task.
The more that php is similar to many languages.